# Perl Moose accessors generated on the fly

Tags: perl, attributes, moose

See the following fragment of Perl code which is based on Moose:

```
$BusinessClass->meta->add_attribute($Key => { is        => $rorw,
                                              isa       => $MooseType,
                                              lazy      => 0,
                                              required  => 0,
                                              reader    => sub { $_[0]->ORM->{$Key} },
                                              writer    => sub { $_[0]->ORM->newVal($Key, $_[1]) },
                                              predicate => "has_$Key",
                                            });
```

I receive the error:

`bad accessor/reader/writer/predicate/clearer format, must be a HASH ref at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.20/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 899`

The reason of the error is clear: reader and writer must be string names of functions.

But what to do it in this specific case? I do not want to create a new function for each of a hundred ORM fields (ORM attribute here is a tied hash). So I can't pass a string here, I need a closure.

Thus my coding needs resulted in a contradiction. I don't know what to do.

---

The above was a fragment of real code. Now I present a minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @Fields = qw( af sdaf gdsg ewwq fsf ); # pretend that we have 100 fields

# Imagine that this is a tied hash with 100 fields 
my %Data = map { $_ => rand } @Fields;

package Test;
use Moose;

foreach my $Key (@Fields) {
  __PACKAGE__->meta->add_attribute($Key => { is        => 'rw',
                                             isa       => 'Str',
                                             lazy      => 0,
                                             required  => 0,
                                             reader    => sub { $Data{$Key} },
                                             writer    => sub { $Data{$Key} = $_[1] },
                                           });
}
```

Running it results in:

```
$ ./test.pl 
bad accessor/reader/writer/predicate/clearer format, must be a HASH ref at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 899
    Class::MOP::Class::try {...}  at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 92
    eval {...} at /usr/share/perl5/Try/Tiny.pm line 83
    Try::Tiny::try('CODE(0x9dc6cec)', 'Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x9ea0c60)') called at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Class/MOP/Class.pm line 904
    Class::MOP::Class::_post_add_attribute('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x9dc13f4)', 'Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x9dc6b5c)') called at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Class/MOP/Mixin/HasAttributes.pm line 39
    Class::MOP::Mixin::HasAttributes::add_attribute('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x9dc13f4)', 'Moose::Meta::Attribute=HASH(0x9dc6b5c)') called at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Moose/Meta/Class.pm line 572
    Moose::Meta::Class::add_attribute('Moose::Meta::Class=HASH(0x9dc13f4)', 'af', 'HASH(0x9ea13a4)') called at test.pl line 18
```

I don't know what to do (how to create "dynamic" (closure-like) accessors, without writing an individual function for each of the 100 fields?)

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] so we can run this?

Comment: The writer is supposed to write into the hash directly, not into an object?

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I think I broke Moose.

Comment: Do you have to use Moose? Do you need the MOP for anything once you are done creating the objects? Or do you just want an OOP-approach to access your tied hash?

Comment: You might find http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=969044 a good read.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, I was ordered to use Moose

Comment: @porton Then your orders are wrong ... Moose doesn't make sense if all you want to do is get/set values in an hash.

Comment: By whom? Do they know what that implies, or is it just a _we do Moose here_ thing? Sometimes arguing pays off if you can actually demonstrate you are right.

Comment: Here's another thing: those very weird and abstract problems tend to attract a lot of _why are you doing this?_ type of questions around here. I have had a few of those questions myself and know that it sometimes feels like this super-complicated approach is the only way to do it. But it actually helps to take a step back and look at what you really want to use it for, and how that thing is supposed to behave on the outside when it's done. Often that way  you can find another, less complicated way. So when we say _don't do that_, we only mean well. :)

Comment: @simbabque It is what my boss assigned me to do. There is no other variants for me (or to change the job)

Comment: That doesn't sound like a happy place.

Answer (score 3):

I think changing the reader and writer methods like that requires an unhealthy level of insanity. If you want to, take a look at [the source code of Class::MOP::Method::Accessor](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/Moose-2.1804/lib/Class/MOP/Method/Accessor.pm), which is used under the hood to create the accessors.

Instead, I suggest to just overwrite (or attach) the functionality to the Moose-generated readers using an `around` method modifier. To get that to work with sub-classes, you can use [Class::Method::Modifiers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers) instead of the Moose `around`.

```
package Foo::Subclass;
use Moose;
extends 'Foo';

package Foo;
use Moose;

package main;
require Class::Method::Modifiers; # no import because it would overwrite Moose

my @Fields = qw( af sdaf gdsg ewwq fsf );    # pretend that we have 100 fields

# Imagine that this is a tied hash with 100 fields
my %Data = map { $_ => rand } @Fields;

my $class = 'Foo::Subclass';
foreach my $Key (@Fields) {
    $class->meta->add_attribute(
        $Key => {
            is       => 'rw',
            isa      => 'Str',
            lazy     => 0,
            required => 0,
        }
    );

    Class::Method::Modifiers::around( "${class}::$Key", sub {
        my $orig = shift;
        my $self = shift;

        $self->$orig(@_);    # just so Moose is up to speed

        # writer
        $Data{$Key} = $_[0] if @_;

        return $Data{$Key};
    });
}
```

And then run a test.

```
package main;
use Data::Printer;
use v5.10;

my $foo = Test->new;
say $foo->sdaf;
$foo->sdaf('foobar');
say $foo->sdaf;

p %Data;
p $foo;
```

Here's the STDOUT/STDERR from my machine.

```
{
    af     0.972962507120432,
    ewwq   0.959195914302605,
    fsf    0.719139421719849,
    gdsg   0.140205658312095,
    sdaf   "foobar"
}
Foo::Subclass  {
   Parents       Foo
    Linear @ISA   Foo::Subclass, Foo, Moose::Object
    public methods (6) : af, ewwq, fsf, gdsg, meta, sdaf
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        sdaf   "foobar"
    }
}
0.885114977459551
foobar
```

As you can see, Moose doesn't really know about the values inside of the hash, but if you use the accessors, it will read and write them. The Moose object will slowly fill up with new values when you use the writer, but otherwise the values inside of the Moose object do not really matter.

Comment: Great solution, but it does not work for me, because in the real code I call `$BusinessClass->meta->add_attribute(...);` in a base class serving for a derived class. Your proposed `around $Key` is called in the base class and fails with an error because `add_attribute()` was called for another (derived) class, and so there is no $Key attribute in the base class. What to do?

Comment: That should work in child classes. I will try when I have a computer.

Comment: @porton I adapted the answer. `Test` was renamed to `Foo` and there is now a subclass. The trick is not to use the Moose `around`.